# 404 error after deleting record Laravel/Livewire3

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a livewire component that dispatches an "eventDeleted" to and ListEvents component so the event list can be updated. When I delete an event I get a 404 error.

This is my ListEvents component:

```
#[On('eventDeleted', 'show-success')]
public function handleEventDeleted()
{

    $this->updateEventList();
}

public function updateEventList()
{
    
    $this->events = $this->domain->events()
                    ->whereNotIn('type', ['website_entry', 'website_exit'])
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                    ->get();
}
```

And my DeleteEvent component

```
public function deleteEvent($eventId)
{
    $event = Event::find($eventId);

    // Check policy
    $this->authorize('delete', $event);

    if ($event) {

        $event->delete();

        $this->closeModal();
        
        // Dispatch event
        $this->dispatch('eventDeleted');
        //Show success message
        $this->dispatch('show-success', message: 'Event Deleted!');

    }
}
```

Its like it is trying to return the delete record before it knows that it has been deleted??